# Calling a Python script from PHP and outputting data back to PHP

Tags: python, php

I have written a simple API in PHP that needs to receive webhook payloads, pass a value to a python script, which will then access a web service via a SOAP client, and return data to the PHP file.

So far I am succesfully receiving the webhook payload into my PHP, executing my python script and passing a value, and receiving output from python back in to my PHP

My PHP endpoint looks like this:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Methods, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Authorization, X-Requested-With');

$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"), true);
$externalUserId = $data['externalUserId'];

$output = shell_exec('/usr/bin/python3 /opt/bitnami/apache/htdocs/test/script.py ' . $externalUserId);
echo $output;
?>
```

My python script looks like this

```
import sys

import datetime
from pathlib import Path
import csv

#import pandas as pd
#from lxml import etree as et
#from suds.client import Client

playerId = sys.argv[1]
print('Player ID is ' + playerId);
```

SO FAR SO GOOD!

BUT - When I attempt to import some libraries in to my python script it stops working. If I uncomment the Pandas, lxml or suds lines the python script no longer returns anything to my PHP.

How can I import these and continue to output data back to PHP?

Are there any suggestions on how to debug this?

Comment: What does `sys.stdout` print **before** your **imports** and what does it print **after** the **imports**?

Comment: A good way to debug this is to check the stderr output. `shell_exec()` Does not give it. That's why you don't see any error stack trace. What you can do is redirecting the stream for the sake of debugging with 
```shell_exec('/usr/bin/python3 /opt/bitnami/apache/htdocs/test/script.py  2>&1' . $externalUserId);``` Please provide the corresponding output. Then we can debug the actual issue.

Comment: Had a typo. Here is the correct line ````shell_exec('/usr/bin/python3 /opt/bitnami/apache/htdocs/test/script.py  ' . $externalUserId . ' 2>&1');````

Comment: Firstly thanks for helping! redirecting the stderr output  give me the error message ``ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'``.

Comment: I have confirmed via pip3 list that pandas is installed. I did a whoami check and can see my Apache is running under username daemon. Is it possible that this user does not have the correct permissions to correctly execute my python and access this library?

Comment: So my issue was that the Python modules had been installed by the bitnami user, not the super user, and so were not awailable when my PHP was calling my Python. I reinstalled using ```sudo pip3 install pandas``` and everything seems to work now. As discussed in this answer ((https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52266273/python-modules-are-not-imported-when-running-python-script-from-php)